# Difference between obj.prop and obj['prop'] in typescript?

Tags: typescript, object, babeljs

After using @babel/parser to parse some string and getting a ast, I encouter an error when logging the ast by the type of obj.prop, but it work when use the type of obj['prop']

```
import { parse } from "@babel/parser";
import traverse from "@babel/traverse";

const ast = parse('{key: "something"}', {
    sourceType: "module",
    plugins: ["typescript"],
});

// Property 'declaration' does not exist on type 'Statement'.  Property 'declaration' does not exist on type 'BlockStatement'.ts(2339)
console.log(ast.program.body[0].declaration.properties);
// it's good
console.log(ast.program.body[0]["declaration"].properties);
```

I'm confused about the difference of the two type writing?

thanks for answer

Answer (score 1):

You can access the properties of an object in JavaScript/typescript :

1. Dot property accessor: object.property
2. Square brackets property access: object['property']

**When to use :**

Choose the **dot** property accessor when the property name is known ahead of time.

eg.

```
const hero = {
  name: 'XYZ'
};
```

Here property is already known ahead of time so we can use hero.name

Choose the **square** brackets property accessor when the property name is dynamic, i.e. determined at runtime.

eg :

```
const property = 'name';
const hero = {
  name: 'XYZ'
};

// Square brackets property accessor:
hero['name'];   //output => 'XYZ'
hero[property]; //output => 'XYZ'
```

Here the property is detemined at runtime so we user square brackets.

So if you use the property dot accessor on the property which is determined at runtime time typescript will give you error

> Property 'name' does not exist on type hero.

There are no good or bad ways to access properties. Choose depending on your particular situation.

Detail explanation is here by [Dmitri Pavlutin](https://dmitripavlutin.com/access-object-properties-javascript/).

Comment: thank for your answer, can I simply understand that the square brackets property access is used in a wider range?

Comment: @happyHacking as i mentioned in my answer square brackets is used when transpiler don't know the object properties beforehand.
In your example may be data is coming from API, so you can use square brakets.
if you want to use the dot accessor then you have to map the response creating model class.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a property in typescript with either dot notation or bracket notation. There is a difference between the two with regards to errors though, depending on compiler options.

If you set `noImplictAny` to `false` (which is the default), you will not get an error with bracket notation even if the property can't be compile time checked to be valid, you just get an implicit `any`. So `ast.program.body[0]["declaration"]` will be `any`, and typescript won't check the `.properties` that comes after. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzmAhlAzgUzgXzgMyghDgCIABAIxUswBsB6VDTKUgbgChRJY4YoKAG6ssBIiQrVajAcNGYOnTgGMIAO3TwUWuAF5kaLAAoA5AgDWmAJ4AuMumKYYAC2DqA5qRymANIk44ILhHAFcoFUwAFWswTHtSEAgAE1C6RV9A4LA6UI93dHsAbVIYWMx0FShgMBhSAF1MnABKLk4GBjgABSI42Gs4U2TMFTo0FBhgDVM4ZIgKuHUIeEwAD2BdDX5ywYBlGAnMEEx1GFMAOiCeiD6yweHR8cnp2fn0ReW4NY34LbK4wYAIToEBUFn2h2OpwuMHQxgATABmREATmaqg0jnS5xBHmMOhg5zARA8ghA50oKWsRQADPVzg8xoJnuoib1WJMKq12p1gGd3h4ICkMZoINjcfitGyIKSUOTKclqXSSoynlN1A1pbdgFz2EA)

If you set `noImplictAny` to true, typescript will complain about not being able to check that `declaration` is indeed a property of `ast.program.body[0]` and you will get errors for both (admittedly, slightly different errors)  [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzmAhlAzgUzgXzgMyghDgCIABAIxUswBsB6VDTKUgbgChRJY4YoKAG6ssBIiQrVajAcNGYOnTgGMIAO3TwUWuAF5kaLAAoA5AgDWmAJ4AuMumKYYAC2DqA5qRymANIk44ILhHAFcoFUwAFWswTHtSEAgAE1C6RV9A4LA6UI93dHsAbVIYWMx0FShgMBhSAF1MnABKLk4GBjgABSI42Gs4U2TMFTo0FBhgDVM4ZIgKuHUIeEwAD2BdDX5ywYBlGAnMEEx1GFMAOiCeiD6yweHR8cnp2fn0ReW4NY34LbK4wYAIToEBUFn2h2OpwuMHQxgATABmREATmaqg0jnS5xBHmMOhg5zARA8ghA50oKWsRQADPVzg8xoJnuoib1WJMKq12p1gGd3h4ICkMZoINjcfitGyIKSUOTKclqXSSoynlN1A1pbdgFz2EA)

You probably want to do some narrowing of the type of `ast.program.body[0]` before you access it's members. Here would be a way to narrow `ast.program.body[0]` to an expression statement and then to an object expression which does have a `properties` member:

```
import { parse } from "@babel/parser";
import { isExpressionStatement, isObjectExpression } from "@babel/types";

const ast = parse('({key: "something"})', {
    sourceType: "module",
    plugins: ["typescript"],
});

let firstStatement = ast.program.body[0];
if (!isExpressionStatement(firstStatement) || !isObjectExpression(firstStatement.expression)) {
    throw Error("Expected statement not found");
}

console.log(firstStatement.expression.properties);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzmAhlAzgUzgXzgMyghDgCIABAIxUswBsB6VDTKUgbgChRJZE5g6AKIAPMFEzp0wCADsAyjBQxMITLJgAaAegDylAFaYAxjFHjJ0ubgJESFarUYwAnmEkdOnY3PTwUfnAAvMhoWAAUAOThCADWmC4AXGToxJgwABbAsgDmpDgAlJHaCJxw5XCpAK5QxpgAKm6YyaQgEAAmVXSYpJplFWB0VTnZ6MkA2qSu7ujGUMBgMKQAun2FXJzd8PjAGDCKyqrq8CEBMAB04hA5UCgg55QdLuMADMtcwPhw4QCEguYSKQyBRKFRqDThHZ7A5g44FOAAHwRcD+ekMJjMYkBVlkkN2fhhRw050wWMswIK8NKFTgmSIAHc4EIoEQoOFSOYMZh2pVQUT4LIINsIFVZO1SAUuDgvD5ZKluuc6Nc8dC+eCLqSLEC5JciO5YMBJJLOEA)

NOTE: I changed `{key: "something"}` to `({key: "something"})`. I assumed you are trying to parse an object literal. Your version was actually a block statement with a labeled statement inside. [Block statement](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/N4awpgngXABARAZwPYFswBcAWBLAdgczgF8g) vs [Object literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/BQbw1gpgngXABAIgM4HsC2EAuALAlgOwHMEBfASiA)